# Hideing GrandTotal Field Of PivotGrid In Developer Express 2010

Tags: devexpress

hi I dont Want to Show The GrandTotal Field Of PivotGrid In Developer Express 2010 So Plz Tell Me How To Hide GrandTotal Field Of PivotGrid In Developer Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in properties there is one optionview  property in that optionview  showgrand total is make false it will hide

Answer (score 0):

```
myPivotGrid.OptionsView.ShowColumnGrandTotals = false;
myPivotGrid.OptionsView.ShowRowGrandTotals = false;
```